# force homepage to https via mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Currently I am using the following code for redirecting my domain name. If someone type my domain name without www then they will be redirected to https. But I also want if someone type www.example.com then it will also redirecting to https. But my current htaccess code is working only for non www.

See my code:

```
# Force homepage to https
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want, if someone type with `www.example.com` or `example.com` then it will be redirected to https.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I modified the regex in your HTTP_HOST pattern. It will match the http host string with or without www now.

```
# Force homepage to https
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your code stopped working for both www or non www. After using your code now my domain not redirecting to https without www. Ah Sad!

Comment: Now homepage is not loading. no page is loading. Browser saying: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: Redirects to https but the page is not loading. And the website is failed to load. Browser says: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: @Aytt The code works fine and I dont think it can produce the Redirect loop error. may be your other rules are conflicting with this one.  Can you post your complete htaccess?

Comment: @starken Please note that, currently I only have wordpress default htaccess code inside of BEGIN AND END wordpress. I don't have any other htaccess code yet. I will use later.

Comment: Here is my current htaccess # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress